# NSSavePanel initialization throws Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) on

Tags: swift, macos, flutter, flutter-packages, nssavepanel

I'm working on a flutter package for all 6 Platforms and now I'd like to open a Save As dialog (I'm total amateur in Swift), so I'm getting an exception when Initializing the object of NSSavePanel, I tried multiple ways, the most basic was

```
let panel = NSSavePanel()
```

and well here I'm getting a exception breakpoint which says Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

So here is my full class where I'm getting the exception

```
class Dialog {
func openSaveAsDialog(params: Params){
    let panel = NSSavePanel()
    panel.directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
    panel.nameFieldStringValue = params.fileName!+"."+params.ext!
    panel.level = .modalPanel
    panel.runModal()
    }
}
```

and as per @EricAya's suggestion in the comment, I'm calling this method as

```
let params = Params(arguments)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let dialog = Dialog()
   dialog.openSaveAsDialog(params: params)
}
```

Comment: Did you add the proper entitlement to your project in Xcode? (disk access)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSSavePanel crash in sandbox app OS X 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366711/nssavepanel-crash-in-sandbox-app-os-x-10-10)

Comment: @EricAya Yes I have, I have allowed all read write access

Comment: @SalmanKhakwani Sorry, I don't understand Objective-C at all, And which answer do you think will fix my problem.

Comment: @EricAya I did try that

Comment: @HassanAnsari Let's try one more thing: are you sure this is executed on the main thread? This could cause this exception if executed in the background.

Comment: @EricAya how can I check that?

Comment: @HassanAnsari DispatchQueue.main.async { *your NSSavePanel code here* }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234118/discussion-between-hassan-ansari-and-eric-aya).

Comment: @HassanAnsari I used your code in a normal macOS test app (not Flutter) and it worked, no error. So I suppose the issue comes from your specific context? Issue may be related to the Params object or the Flutter environment for example.

Comment: @EricAya probably yes